# Is there a way to use the FOSUserBundle without a mailer service

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

I want to use FOSUserBundle but my application doesn't require a mailer service. Is there anyway I can configure it to not require one.
Heres my config for fos:

```
fos_user:
  db_driver: orm 
  firewall_name: main
  user_class: acmeBundle/Custom/User/Class
```

I've tried to configure it like so:

```
fos_user:
  db_driver: orm 
  firewall_name: main
  user_class: acmeBundle/Custom/User/Class
  service:
    mailer: ~
```

But I get this error:

```
InvalidArgumentException: $id must be a string, or an Alias object.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually mentioned in the docs. You can specify `fos_user.mailer.noop` when you don't want to send out mails.

You can find all relevant info in the [Default mailer implementations](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/emails.md#default-mailer-implementations) chapter of the emails documentation.

Answer (score 4):

You need to inject noop-mailer. It will not require mailer-service and will not send any emails.

```
fos_user:
  db_driver: orm 
  firewall_name: main
  user_class: acmeBundle/Custom/User/Class
  service:
    mailer: fos_user.mailer.noop
```